# Sliding View from bottom

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I haven't seen any discussion on Google's latest slew of Application updates on this new paradigm of sliding a view up from the bottom of the screen and having it overlay the current UI.

For example the new Google Music application does this while your listening to a song, you can slide up and it will hide the ActionBar when it reaches a certain threshold. I have some screenshots to illustrate what I'm trying to explain.

[image]

You can slide this up from the bottom and it has Audio controls if I continued to slide and when it reaches a certain point on the Y axis the ActionBar slides upwards to make room for the new view. I've never seen anything like it before. As well the new Google Maps Update that just came out does the same thing. When you search for a destination you can slide up from the bottom of the screen and when it reaches the threshold it will hide the search window and the new view will just overlay the entire Map view.

I looked into the Google Maps update a little more and it is a custom view there using they called it ***ExpandingScrollView***. I mean that's not much help at all but it isn't something that comes stock in the SDK or in the support library.

If anyone has any insight on possibly how to do this or any information that would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be helpful: [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)